# Inspecting C Header Files Further

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio-2013, header-files, msdn

I am learning networking in c by looking at the code of a working packet sniffer within **Microsoft Visual Basic 2013**.

Below is code that creates a pointer to a *hostent structure*, obtains the *localhost hostname*, and loads it into the *hostent structure* called *local*.

```
struct hostent *local;
gethostname(hostname, sizeof(hostname))
local = gethostbyname(hostname);
```

The next part enables the address to be printed in dotted decimal notation.

```
for (i = 0; local->h_addr_list[i] != 0; ++i)
{
    memcpy(&addr, local->h_addr_list[i], sizeof(struct in_addr));
    printf("  Interface Number : %d Address : %s\n",i,inet_ntoa(addr));
}
```

Now, I want to understand how all this works and more . . .

Say I want to understand inet_ntoa(), I right-click and choose **Go To Definition** or **Go To Declaration** and it sends me to **WinSock2.h** that shows:

```
inet_ntoa(
    __in struct in_addr in
);
```

This appears to be show me the parameter but not the workings of the function or the return value. This means I have to refer to the **MSDN** to understand what is happening every time.

My question is: Where is the code to read what is happening so I don't have to use the docs?

E.g. where is the `inet_ntoa` function contents?

Comment: `inet_ntoa` is implemented in a system DLL, specifically `Ws2_32.dll`.  There is no Microsoft Source available.  You will be able to find open source implementations available for other platforms.  Linux docs are here http://linux.die.net/man/3/inet_ntoa

Comment: This is implemented in many [tag:c] libraries, for example *glibc* implements it and you can read it's code since you can download the whole *glibc*. It's cerainly not implemented in header files.

Comment: Is that a _full_ quote from WinSock2.h? Because the function declaration appears to lack a return type, which shouldn't work at all.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms738564(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you are:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>

/* The interface of this function is completely stupid, it requires a
   static buffer.  We relax this a bit in that we allow one buffer for
   each thread.  */

static __thread char buffer[18];

char *inet_ntoa (struct in_addr in)
{
   unsigned char *bytes = (unsigned char *) &in;
   __snprintf (buffer, sizeof (buffer), "%d.%d.%d.%d",
               bytes[0], bytes[1], bytes[2], bytes[3]);

  return buffer;
}
```

Taken from **inet_ntoa.c**, *glibc 2.23*

Remember that the **glibc is open source**, so if you want to explore a bit and learn what's going in under the hood, don't hesitate and download it !

Regards

Comment: Thank you for the response buy how do I find where this is located?

Comment: @Phoenix You can download the *glibc* code and then do something like `find . -type f -name '*.c' -exec grep -nH --color "inet_ntoa" {} \;` from the root directory of the code. Then you can find where it is implemented.

Comment: It's better to provide a live link to the source: https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=inet/inet_ntoa.c;hb=HEAD (not that I expect this one to change much :P ...also, funny comment there)

Comment: @iharob `find /path/to/glibc -type f -name inet_ntoa.c` is enough =)

Comment: tangential: here is a thread discussing the questionable interface of this function and the availability of `inet_ntop()`, which uses the kind of interface many of us would've expected all along: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1705885/why-inet-ntoa-is-designed-to-be-a-non-reentrant-function

Comment: @underscore_d I added the includes and the comment ;)

Comment: Good enough I guess, but the OP asked for Microsoft code and this is something else.

Comment: @SvenNilsson Good point. I guess it depends on whether the OP only wants to know what the function _must_ do, rather than specifically how it does it. But then - setting aside API docs - often the function signature would make the former fairly clear. I'm confused by why it appears to lack a return type in the OP's quote.

Comment: @LiGhTx117 Why would you assume anything about the name of the  implementation file? It's not mandatory.